# My leg was hurt / I hurt myself on my leg

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which of the following sentences are natural and idiomatic?

> a. My leg was hurt in an accident.

> b. I hurt myself on my leg in an accident.

> c. I was hurt on my leg in an accident.

Answer (score 1):

Among the three options you have provided, I think only the first one (My leg was hurt in an accident) can be considered correct.

However, the natural way of putting it is:

*I hurt my leg in an accident.*

Comment: Does "I hurt my leg in an accident" mean the same as (a)?

Comment: @Apollyon yes, it does.